# C# Dynamic Class Name Only --> Generated at Run-Time

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, classname

This is strictly for learning purposes of OOP.

I have a Hierarchy of inheritance that WANTS to look like this:

```
`    
     -> Fruit->0-n fruits classes
     -> Vegetable -> 0-n vegetable classes
 Food-> Milk -> 0-n milk classes
     -> Grain -> 0-n grain classes
     -> Meat -> 0-n meat classes
`
```

The base class is a Food, all fruit/vegetable/milk/grain/meat extend food. Then the fruit class might have a child that is of Apple,Banana,Lemon type etc. So Apple,Banana,Lemon will be extending fruit, which extends food.

Now as you can imagine, there are a lot of different types of fruits/vegetables/milks/grains/meat in the world. Too many to make an individual class for each one.

What I want to accomplish is this:

1. Create a dynamic class whose identifying ClassName type will change based on what the user has input.

The functionality looks similar to this:

```
public class ${ClassName} : ${Category}{
//Imagine I can put a variable name right where ${ClassName} is that holds Banana.  
//I'd then determine ${Category} simply from the location that the user entered the value Banana.

//I'd now have: 
}   public class Banana : Fruit{

}
```

In this scenario, I'm not concerned with any varying of methods/variables/properties in the class. They will all stay the same, I only wish for the ClassName to change to the appropriate name.

Is this possible? Or am I in fairy tale land? Ideally, after the above method is successful. I'd like to be able to get the ClassName using object.getType() and have it return something like Apple,Banana,Lemon, if the user entered one of these.

Comment: I think you do not have the concept of classes yet, *Banana* is the name of a fruit and should not be a class. So it rather will be a name property that sits inside the fruit class. Same as the type of fruit will be a property. Think about persons. *Person* will be a class ... but hes name "John" won't. Look to classes like it's a *thing* not the specifications of a *thing* itself.

Comment: I personally would not do things this way. This is an exercise to see if this type of functionality is possible at all. I was looking into C# Dynamic Classes, and wondering if that specific section even holds what I'm asking.

Comment: I agree with @Jim, typically in OOD, a class has a unique set of parameters and functions, and if two objects should not have different abilities, they should be the same class. For example, if we have a class `Drinks` with a name and the fuction `void drink()`, that would cover water, milk, soda, etc.  You can load the names in from the user input without the hassle of trying to create derived types on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jim's comment, I think you have the wrong idea about classes. Ideally (depending on the domain) you'd want to model the Fruit base class with a property for Name. "Banana" is a Fruit, "Apple" is a Fruit, ...and so on.

```
public class Fruit { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you really needed to get specific, you could create classes that use Fruit as a base class. Probably along the lines of Berry, Drupe, Legume, etc. And then you'd still want a Name property to define what the specific instance of the fruit is "Raspberry", "Blueberry", ...

```
public class Berry : Fruit { 
    // berry-specific properties
}
```

Once you have a more fundamental understanding about classes and structuring them, as well as the difference between a concrete and abstract type, I'd recommend you look at the [Factory Method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) and [Abstract Factory](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) design patterns. Those describe techniques you can use if you truly need to determine the concrete type at runtime.

Comment: I'm not claiming this is a good idea to do in my OP, or if it's what you should do. I know I can simply be less specific and take away the 3rd layer in my hierarchy, then leave it to simply getting the input from the user and putting it straight into a variable in one of the fruit/meat/grain/milk/vegetable classes. 

 I'm only asking if it's possible. 

And the reason I would want to do it this way, is that some fruits can have additional properties to them. Example, There are many different types of Apples, (Granny Smith, Golden Delicious, Honeycrisp, Red Delicious, etc).

Comment: A bookish answer, but in that case I would focus on composition over inheritance (Decorator Pattern). https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator And focus on determining what makes a specific type of apple a GrannySmith or HoneyCrisp. Sweetness = 9, Tartness = 4, or what have you. There is likely a better way to represent the data than creating new Classes for "all-the-things"

However, your posted question was in regards to determining/creating a concrete type at runtime, which can be done with a factory pattern.